# Why does the new method use a parenthesis for its argument whereas the render method doesn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been studying Rails for a while and I don't understand when to use a parenthesis for a method since there seems to be no consistency in my eyes.

```
def create
   post.new(post_params)
 if @post.save
   redirect_to root_path
 else
   render 'new'
end
```

end

Comment: I read somewhere that when the first argument to a method is a hash parenthesis are optional, see the [ruby code style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) for details.

Comment: @ImranAli, Nothing to do with first argument to a method. There are some cases when there is a difference which one you use (mostly when parentheses or blocks are involved), but in OP the only difference is a stylistic one. `post.new post_params` and `redirect_to(root_path)` would work just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there's no consistency.

```
def create
  post.new(post_params)
  if @post.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

could also be written:

```
def create()
  post.new post_params
  if @post.save()
    redirect_to(root_path)
  else
    render('new')
  end
end
```

Both methods would work exactly the same.

There are [style guidelines](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide), though.

> Always omit parentheses for method calls with no arguments.
>
> Always omit parentheses for methods that are part of an internal DSL (e.g., Rake, Rails, RSpec).
>
> Use def with parentheses when there are parameters. Omit the parentheses when the method doesn't accept any parameters.
>
> Use parentheses around the arguments of method invocations

The first method seems to apply those guidelines, the second one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Because all in ruby and ruby on rails it is object.

example

```
class People
  def info(name, age, color)
    puts name
    puts age
    puts color
  end
end
people = People.new
people.info("Juanito", "34", "Blue")
```